# Error using setlabels(Matlab)

Tags: matlab, object, matrix, size, label

The I have two matrix x and y and both are having the same size; but the issue is when I provide the following command to matlab

```
X = prdataset([x;y],[ones(size(x,1),1);zeros(size(y,1),1)]);
```

I got this error

```
 Error using setlabels (line 79)
Numbers of objects and labels do not match
```

I wonder how come it happens even i check both x and y are having the same data size

Can someone point me out what is happening in my code. Note that I am using prtools

Comment: It is dataset class constructor provided by prtools

Comment: according to the documentation: First parameter of prdataset is a matfile